# How to skip empty keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a better way to avoid redundant code? As in this case, if `storage` is 0 then I don't want to pass it to the function and keep code neat, but I had to do a if-else.

```
if storage == 0:
    response_lc = asg_client.create_launch_configuration(
        ImageId=ami,
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        KeyName=keypair
    )
else:
    response_lc = asg_client.create_launch_configuration(
        VolumeSize=storage,
        ImageId=ami,
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        KeyName=keypair
    )
```

Comment: How is this neater than passing a zero value? Why doesn't `create_launch_configuration` deal with that value? Could you use e.g. `storage or None`?

Comment: This is a vendor api and fails if no value passed, let me try the 'None'

Comment: None type is not valid :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no way out, you can do this:

```
kwargs = {
  "ImageId": ami,
  "InstanceType": instance_type,
  "KeyName": keypair
}
if storage:
    kwargs["VolumeSize"] = storage

response_lc = asg_client.create_launch_configuration(**kwargs)
```

But I will advise you to dig into the `asg_client.create_launch_configuration` method and see if all the four parameters can be passed in all the cases.